# Ubuntu system no longer boots, recovery menu is a little wonky

Tags: boot, 16.04

I've got an Ubuntu system that hadn't been updated in a long time because of an issue with the ROCM repo (Radeon open compute), and now that I finally wound up restarting it, I'm having some issues.

When I try to boot normally, the screen goes black after mounting disks and then restarts from the BIOS screen. In the GRUB Recovery Menu, I usually get [a messed up screen with some terminal text over top of the recovery GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73eJV.jpg).

If I manage to get the Recovery Menu working, it misses a ton of my keypresses at random. Holding a key down once resulted in white terminal text on a red background issuing a warning about input overrun at /dev/tty1space. The system has trouble booting regardless of whether or not the keyboard is connected. The keyboard works when booting to Windows and has previously worked with Ubuntu on this same machine. I suspect this /dev/tty1space issue is a strange side effect of the root issue. (e.g. maybe the CPU is working very hard polling some other hardware and only gets to check in on the keyboard every now and then or something silly like that) I strongly suspect the issue is related to some OS internals or the ROCM driver, but I don't know how to diagnose this.

Where can I look to figure out what's wrong with this system and try to make it bootable again? I think I'm on 16.04, but I can't even get it far enough to check that.

Comment: The keyboard works fine when booting to Windows and has previously worked on this machine.

Comment: Having trouble getting fsck to run in the borked recovery menu.

Comment: Time to boot into Windows and make a new install USB. Run fsck using that. If it fails, reinstall..

Comment: I got fsck to run on everything but the partition holding /, which the recovery menu couldn't do because it was busy... This is a RAMdisk, right? Why can't I unmount the boot drive's root directory from a ramdisk?